# wrong database name showing on my main form

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

It seems I cant get this to work properly. Somehow I am messing the "if then"
sequence.

I got this on a login form:

```
procedure TLogin_Form.AdvGlowButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Data_Module.LOGIN.Active:=false;
  Data_Module.LOGIN.SQL.Clear;
  Data_Module.LOGIN.SQL.Text:= 'select [LOC_ID],[USER],[PASSWORD],[ACCESS] from USERS where [USER] ='+QuotedStr(cxlookupcombobox1.text) +' and [PASSWORD]='+QuotedStr(cxTextEdit1.Text);
  Data_Module.LOGIN.Open;

  if Data_Module.LOGIN.FieldByName('PASSWORD').AsString<>'' then
  begin
    if Data_Module.LOGIN.FieldByName('LOC_ID').AsInteger = 1 then
      Data_Module.ACRDatabase1.DatabaseFileName := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+ '..\database\db1.adb';
    Data_Module.ACRDatabase1.DatabaseName :='database1';
    Data_Module.ACRDatabase1.Connected:=True;
    if Data_Module.LOGIN.FieldByName('LOC_ID').AsInteger = 2 then
      Data_Module.ACRDatabase1.DatabaseFileName := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+ '..\database\db2.adb';
    Data_Module.ACRDatabase1.DatabaseName :='database2';
    Data_Module.ACRDatabase1.Connected:=True;
    ModalResult := mrOK
  end
  else
    ModalResult := mrNone;

  cxtextEdit1.Clear;
  dxStatusBar1.Panels[1].Text :='wrong password !';
  cxtextEdit1.SetFocus;
end;
```

ModalResult OK shows the main form.

Just to check the database name if it shows right....

```
procedure TMain_Form.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Data_Module.ACRDatabase1.Connected then
    AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels[0].Text := Data_Module.ACRDatabase1.DatabaseName
  else
    AdvOfficeStatusBar1.Panels[0].Text :='';
end;
```

Somehow, I end up with the wrong database name on my mainform.
What am I doing wrong ? Tried various ways but failed.

Also I am wondering if "case" statement can be used here like this:

> case Data_Module.LOGIN.FieldByName('LOC_ID').Value of 1:begin

since I have about 5 databases to choose from ?

Comment: Please do not concatenate your SQL statement, you are vulnerable to SQL injection! Use parameters instead...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we use Begin End blocks when we write multiple lines of code.

```
procedure TLogin_Form.AdvGlowButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Data_Module.LOGIN.Active:=false;
  Data_Module.LOGIN.SQL.Clear;
  Data_Module.LOGIN.SQL.Text:= 'select [LOC_ID],[USER],[PASSWORD],[ACCESS]     from USERS where [USER] ='+QuotedStr(cxlookupcombobox1.text) +' and     [PASSWORD]='+QuotedStr(cxTextEdit1.Text);
  Data_Module.LOGIN.Open;

  if Data_Module.LOGIN.FieldByName('PASSWORD').AsString<>'' then
  begin
    if Data_Module.LOGIN.FieldByName('LOC_ID').AsInteger = 1 then
      begin
        Data_Module.ACRDatabase1.DatabaseFileName :=     ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+ '..\database\db1.adb';
        Data_Module.ACRDatabase1.DatabaseName :='database1';
      End
    else if Data_Module.LOGIN.FieldByName('LOC_ID').AsInteger = 2 then
      begin
        Data_Module.ACRDatabase1.DatabaseFileName :=     ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+ '..\database\db2.adb';
        Data_Module.ACRDatabase1.DatabaseName :='database2';
      end;

    Data_Module.ACRDatabase1.Connected:=True;
    ModalResult := mrOK
  end
  else
    ModalResult := mrNone;

  cxtextEdit1.Clear;
  dxStatusBar1.Panels[1].Text :='wrong password !';
  cxtextEdit1.SetFocus;
end;
```

yes, you can use the case statement like that.

with case of statement

```
  case Data_Module.LOGIN.FieldByName('LOC_ID').AsInteger of
    1:Begin
      Data_Module.ACRDatabase1.DatabaseFileName :=     ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+ '..\database\db1.adb';
      Data_Module.ACRDatabase1.DatabaseName :='database1';
    End;
    2:Begin
      Data_Module.ACRDatabase1.DatabaseFileName :=     ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)+ '..\database\db2.adb';
      Data_Module.ACRDatabase1.DatabaseName :='database2';
    End;
  end;
```

Comment: wonderful .... can you show me how CASE statement in this example  should look like ?

Comment: Are you seriously saying that you can't look up the syntax of a case statement in the OLH?

Comment: @user763539 have a look at my answer, i've updated it.

Comment: @MartynA no,I actually tried the case statement first  but I am unsure where to start the CASE and where to put the last part (end else) ...